# code failing for multiple inputs

Tags: c++, c++11

Here is a question of C++ that I was practising on some other site. The code is given below. My code fails for multiple inputs. the output is only

```
clee olg
```

instead of

```
clee olg
sho col
```

**Problem statement :**

Given a string, `S`, of length `N` that is indexed from `0` to `N-1`, print its even-indexed and odd-indexed characters as space-separated strings on a single line.

INPUT- 
The first line contains an integer, `t` (the number of test cases). 
Each line `i` of the subsequent lines contain a String, `S`

OUTPUT-
For each String `S` (where `0<= j<=N-1`), print `S`'s even-indexed characters, followed by a space, followed by `S`'s odd-indexed characters.

Eg-

```
2
college
school
```

output-

```
clee olg
sho col
```

**code :**

```
int main() 
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    string str;
    vector<string>s_even;
    vector<string>s_odd;
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        getline(cin,str);

        for(int j=0;j<str.size();j++)
        {        
            if(j%2==0)
                 { 
                   string  a;
                   a=str[j];
                   s_even.push_back(a);

                 }
             else
                 { 
                   string b;
                   b= str[j];
                   s_odd.push_back(b);
                  }
           }

copy(s_even.begin(),s_even.end(),ostream_iterator<string>(cout));

cout<<" ";

copy(s_odd.begin(),s_odd.end(),ostream_iterator<string>(cout));

 str.clear();
 s_odd.clear();
 s_even.clear();
 }
 return 0;

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Comment: Simplest fix: `std::cin >> t >> std::ws;` where you read in the count

Comment: Aside: You don't need `std::vector<std::string>`s, you can just `push_back` into a single string. You can then `std::cout << evens << " " << odds << std::endl;`

Answer (score 0):

When debugging it might be helpful to print out your intermediate results. This can help you pinpoint the source of failure. For example if you had printed out `str` after your `getline(cin, str)`, you'll notice that your first iteration gives you an empty string.

As for why, and the solution, check out the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction?rq=1) by @Mat